# How do I embed javascript directly into my ASP.net Custom Control?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, custom-controls, custom-server-controls

I am building my first user control and I would like to package the javascript required for the control with the assembly so the end user does not have to worry about including dependencies.  I've followed a tutorial from Scott Mitchell (https://web.archive.org/web/20210510023046/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080906-1.aspx) but I can't seem to get it to work right.

Here is what I've done so far:

I've created a CollapsiblePanel.js file that contains the following function:

```
function TogglePanel(panelId) {
    //    $(panelId + ' .PanelContent').toggle();
    alert(panelId);
}
```

Under the properties panel I set the Build Action to "Embedded Resource".  This file resides in a scripts/ directory inside my class library project.  The root namespace of my project is webstation.WebControls so if my understanding is correct I should be referencing the js file via "webstation.WebControls.scripts.CollapsiblePanel.js"

I've added the following line just before my class declaration for the custom control:

```
<Assembly: WebResource("webstation.WebControls.scripts.CollapsiblePanel.js", "text/javascript")>
```

I've overridden the OnPreRender event in my Custom Control and added the following:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("wsWebControlsCollapsiblePanel", _
                  Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(Me.GetType(), "webstation.WebControls.scripts.CollapsiblePanel.js"))

    MyBase.OnPreRender(e)

End Sub
```

When I render my control I have a button with the function "TogglePanel(this.id);" in the onclick event, but when I click the button I get an error saying that the function is not defined.  If anyone knows how I might begin using my embedded javascript I would really appreciate the help,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it,

The problem was I included 'scripts' in the resource name so that I had "webstation.WebControls.scripts.CollapsiblePanel.js"

I decided to try it so I had:
"webstation.WebControls.CollapsiblePanel.js"

and that did the trick.

It's a little confusing because all the documentation specifically states including the path as part of the naming convention, but perhaps I did something wrong when including a folder in the project.

Mike